# OleDbException was unhandled [Newbie here]

Tags: vb.net

i got error in this code please 
i need this in school its a group project but im only doing this because they dont know how to code, so i participate to do this program, im a begginer in vb, i hope you understand, Thank you :)

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form9

    Private Sub Form9_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'FoodDataSet.Table1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

        Table1BindingSource.AddNew()


    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            TextBox1.Text = ("Burger P 12")
        ElseIf RadioButton1.Checked = False Then
            TextBox1.Text = ("Choose Your Order!")

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
        If RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
            TextBox1.Text = ("Cheese Burger = P 15")
        ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = False Then
            TextBox1.Text = ("Choose Your Order!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton3.CheckedChanged
        If RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
            TextBox1.Text = ("Ham Burger = P 15")
        ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked = False Then
            TextBox1.Text = ("Choose Your Order!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Hide()


    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton4_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton4.CheckedChanged
        If RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
            TextBox2.Text = ("Potato = P 10")
        ElseIf RadioButton4.Checked = False Then
            TextBox2.Text = ("Choose Your Order!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton5_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton5.CheckedChanged
        If RadioButton5.Checked = True Then
            TextBox2.Text = ("Piatos = P 12")
        ElseIf RadioButton5.Checked = False Then
            TextBox2.Text = ("Choose Your Order!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton6_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton6.CheckedChanged
        If RadioButton6.Checked = True Then
            TextBox2.Text = ("Potato Fries = P 15")
        ElseIf RadioButton6.Checked = False Then
            TextBox2.Text = ("Choose Your Order!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton11_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton11.CheckedChanged
        If RadioButton11.Checked = True Then
            TextBox3.Text = ("Coke = P 10")
        ElseIf RadioButton11.Checked = False Then
            TextBox3.Text = ("Choose Your Order!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton8_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton8.CheckedChanged
        If RadioButton8.Checked = True Then
            TextBox3.Text = ("Sprite = P 10")
        ElseIf RadioButton8.Checked = False Then
            TextBox3.Text = ("Choose Your Order!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton9_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton9.CheckedChanged
        If RadioButton9.Checked = True Then
            TextBox3.Text = ("Royal = P 10")
        ElseIf RadioButton9.Checked = False Then
            TextBox3.Text = ("Choose Your Order!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim con As OleDbConnection
        Table1BindingSource.AddNew()
        MessageBox.Show("Your Orders in ongoing,Kindly Prepare your money and wait your order, Thank you!")

        Me.Validate()
        Me.Table1BindingSource.EndEdit()
        con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\WinXP\Desktop\LoadTest HP\WindowsApplication1\Food.mdb")

        Me.Table1TableAdapter.Update(Me.FoodDataSet.Table1)



    End Sub
    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Table1BindingSource.RemoveCurrent()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton7_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton7.CheckedChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Form10.Show()
        Me.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There's quite a bit of code there and much of it is clearly irrelevant.  We shouldn't have to wade through irrelevant code because you couldn't be bothered working out what needs to be posted and what doesn't.  Post only the relevant code and also point out exactly where the error occurs.  People here are happy to help but we don't want to waste time working things out that you already know and can tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you have a possible exception that wasn't handled you should handle the exception which will even show you a error which can further help you figure out what's wrong with your code :)

How do you handle exceptions? wrap code which uses OleDB with try/catch anywhere you use OleDb you should try/catch it.. remove the try/catch later when you know your code works 100%.

like so..

```
Try
  con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\WinXP\Desktop\LoadTest HP\WindowsApplication1\Food.mdb")
Catch ex as OleDbException
  Msgbox ex.ToString()
End Try
```

I would wrap where you declare the `OleDbConnection` as well which is not necessary but it gets all the OleDb stuff in a try/catch

```
Try
        Dim con As OleDbConnection
        Table1BindingSource.AddNew()
        MessageBox.Show("Your Orders in ongoing,Kindly Prepare your money and wait your order, Thank you!")

        Me.Validate()
        Me.Table1BindingSource.EndEdit()
        con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\WinXP\Desktop\LoadTest HP\WindowsApplication1\Food.mdb")
Catch ex as OleDbException
        Msgbox ex.ToString()
End Try
```